# GPS not working in Android app in China

Tags: android, gps

Can somebody from China please confirm whether Google Location Services work in China. An android app which is using Mapquest location based service isn't able to detect the GPS. Any alternative solution would be acceptable. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check whether the network connection is blocked or not ?

Comment: No it is not blocked.

Comment: try with another app, on the same device. try a device from another manufacturer.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, yes it is working. I am able to connect succesfully.

Location: China, Fujian Xiamen

Methods:

1. Wifi on + gps on = working
2. Wifi off + gps on = working
3. Wifi on + gps off = working
4. 3G on + gps = working
5. 3G off + gps = working

All tested without VPN.
Apps used: Google Maps, Navigation

Don't know if 3G has an actual impact on the accuracy or not. Not a GEO loc expert.

Comment: Hi have you checked in china? As we the same code working fine in other places but only if we enter china physically its not working.

Comment: @Naresh Noby Yes I have, in my post it sais Location: China, Fujian Xiamen.  Xiamen is a city in the PROVICE Fujian, which is a province of China